# Asp.Net Trying to set programmatically buttons in a loop

Tags: asp.net, button

This is my code:

```
 <% for (int i = 1; i < rptTotPages; i++)
 {
 %>
     <asp:Button runat="server" 
                 Text="<%:i%>" 
                 CommandName="RptPager" 
                 CommandArgument="<%:i%>" 
                 OnCommand="RptPagerCommand"/>

 <%  } %>
```

But what I get is a series of button with text: <%:i%>

what I would like is to replace the i with its value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use asp:repeater control

**Code Behind**

In Page_Load event:

```
if(!IsPostBack) {
  IEnumerable pageNums = Enumerable.Range(1, rptTotPages);
  rptrPages.DataSource = pageNums;
  rptrPages.DataBind();
}
```

**ASPX:**

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptrPages" runat="server">  
          <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:Button runat="server" 
                 Text="<%# Container.DataItem %>" 
                 CommandName="RptPager" 
                 CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItem %>" 
                 OnCommand="RptPagerCommand"/>
          </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```